# Pandas use previous row's value depending on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, stock

Please assist on making calculations based on df.Decision, referencing values from previous df.Decision row.

**Requirements**: After the first "Buy" decision, the next "Sell" decision needs to take the previous buy-decision's shares amount and multiplies it by the sell-decision's "Close" amount. The subsequent "Buy" would then take the previous "Sell" row's dollars and multiple by the buy-decision's "Close" amount; the buy-decision shares and then calculated using quotient operation (Dollars * (Dollars // Close)).

In essence, each 'buy' and 'sell' decision iterates. I am just simplifying the data. Note that there is always a first "Buy" decision already made.

Any assistance is appreciated! Explanation/tutorial links that can be useful would also be appreciated.

**Current Data**

| Date | Close | Decision | Dollars | Shares | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-1 | 67.9554214477539 | Sell |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-02 | 71.8088455200195 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-03 | 76.5043106079102 | Buy | 994.556037902832 | 13 |  |
| 2020-02-24 | 72.7082214355469 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-26 | 72.7082214355469 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-27 | 67.9554214477539 | Sell |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-28 | 67.9156646728516 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-03-02 | 74.2386627197266 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-04-23 | 68.3305816650391 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-04-24 | 70.3032531738281 | Buy |  |  |  |
| 2020-04-27 | 70.3529434204102 |  |  |  |  |

**Expected Data**

| Date | Close | Decision | Dollars | Shares | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-1 | 67.9554214477539 | Sell |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-02 | 71.8088455200195 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-03 | 76.5043106079102 | Buy | 994.556037902832 | 13 |  |
| 2020-02-24 | 72.7082214355469 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-26 | 72.7082214355469 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-27 | 67.9554214477539 | Sell | 883.420478820801 | 13 | -11.174388857603 |
| 2020-02-28 | 67.9156646728516 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-03-02 | 74.2386627197266 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-04-23 | 68.3305816650391 |  |  |  |  |
| 2020-04-24 | 70.3032531738281 | Buy | 843.639038085937 | 12 |  |
| 2020-04-27 | 70.3529434204102 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I believe df.loc and shift() must be used but I haven't been successful yet..

Comment: At what point is the number of shares to be traded determined? Does it mean that the same number of shares will be sold as the number of shares purchased as a requirement?

Comment: While the first 'buy' decision is based on a $1000 investment, any subsequent sale and purchase is based on money either made or lost. Decision to sell triggers a sale of the previously bought shares (eg 13). Any subsequent purchases are based on the amount of money from the previous sale's dollar amount.
Also: yes, you would be selling the same number of shares you bought in the previous buy-decision.